# Ruby Slim format for table

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a question about the syntax for [Slim](http://slim-lang.com/)

I have this code

```
  thead
    tr
      th Collection Names
  tbody
    td
      - @collection.each do |c|
        = c.name
```

Rails keeps on throwing the "Malformed indentation" error for the tag **td** for some reason. I'm a newbie in Slim. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

I think you forgot to put your `td` tag isn't inside of a `tr` tag.

```
thead
  tr
    th Collection Names
tbody
  tr
    td
      - @collection.each do |c|
        = c.name
```

Comment: Actually I realized why I couldn't get it to work now but thanks anyway!

Comment: Well, post your answer. Someone else will benefit, if it turned out to be something else.

Answer (score 1):

Today i got same problem : ) if u use sublime text, trans true to false,it works fine!

`"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": false,`

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for syntax, but quite often an issue with Ruby Slim is the consistency of tabs vs spaces when copying code from various websites.

i.e. where - is a tab aligned to two spaces, and . is a space

```
thead
-tr
--th
# ^ will work

thead
..tr
....th
# ^ so will this

thead
..tr
-..th
# ^ will produce malformed alignment error
```

Comment: Dear lord those tabs had me crazy. Thanks dude!